# Which font and size does apple use for the navigation bar title?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I made an totally custom navigation bar and would like to use the exact same font and size like apple does for the title of their navigation bar. It looks like some kind of fat printed arial, but not sure if that's right. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Definitely not Arial. It's Helvetica. You can probably get the same font using

```
UIFont *navFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
```

Change the size to find out what Apple is using (and write it below in a comment if you find the best one).

All the navigation bar text has a white shadow underneath it to give it the embossed effect. It's a white shadow 1 pixel underneath the text. Use `shadowColor` and `shadowOffset` in a `UILabel` to get the same effect.

Comment: I believe it's 15. Going to have to experiment a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: They use `HelveticaNeue-Medium` in the NavBar, and the system `labelFontSize` is `17.0` (on post iOS7).

Answer (score 53):

**iOS12 - iOS15 Large Title** - System Bold 34 (San Francisco)

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:34]
```

**iOS9 - iOS15 Regular centered title** - System Semibold 17 (San Francisco)

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17 weight:UIFontWeightSemibold]
```

**iOS8** - System Semibold 17 (Helvetica Neue)

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17 weight:UIFontWeightSemibold]
```

**iOS7** - System Bold 17 (Helvetica Neue)

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
```

Nice link about typo in iOS
https://learnui.design/blog/ios-font-size-guidelines.html

Comment: How did you find these, out of interest?

Comment: Also curious how you found these out.  I am creating a custom view and would like to dynamically grab these values if possible.

Comment: Use the "Debug View Hierarchy" use http://apple.co/2aPwI4V for more info :)

Answer (score 1):

For iOS7 the correct font size is 17pt:

```
UIFont *navFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIFont *navFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
```